# How is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Let $n\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integer multiples of $n \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can someone explain how $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Specifically, what is the function that establishes the isomorphism, and how can we be sure it is bijective?

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb Z_n$ ?

Comment: $Z_n$ is the ring of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: To me $\mathbb Z_n$ is defined as $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is the same, so there is nothing to show.

Comment: I'm reading Stewart and Tall *Algebraic Number Theory* and Fermat's Last Theorem.  The sentence is from their book page 11.

Comment: @LarryFreeman what is your definition of an integer modulo $n$? What is your definition of a quotient of a group by a subgroup?

Comment: I'm very confused about understanding the quotient of a group which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Since you used the tag "ring-theory", I thought you were asking about the quotient of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ by its ideal $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, I guess that I should not have used that tag for such an elementary question.

Comment: I don't mind your using the tag however elementary the question, it's just asking for a clarification whether you have groups or rings in mind (as an earlier Comment also suggested).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably we can denote the elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ as $[a]_n$ where $a \in \Bbb Z$ and $[a]_n$ denotes the equivalence class of $a$ modulo $n$.

On the other hand, the elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ can be written as cosets of the form $a + n\Bbb Z$.

We can define an isomorphism between these groups by the map
$$
[a]_n \mapsto a + n\Bbb Z
$$

---

Note, however, that $[a]_n$ and $a + n\Bbb Z$ are equal as sets and the group operation is precisely the same, so the isomorphism of these two groups is fairly trivial.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I figured that it was trivial but I was unclear so it was nontrivial for me.  Your answer really helps!

Comment: In fact since $[a]_n=a+n\Bbb Z$, this is not just an isomorphism of groups but an ***equality*** of groups - they're literally the same group with the same elements, the elements only notated or referenced slightly differently (e.g. "equivalence class" versus "coset").

Comment: The concept of "coset" is not yet intuitive to me.  The concept of "equivalence class" is very clear.