# Proof of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: group-theory

I'm referring the proof of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/z-nz-is-isomorphic-to-zn

[image]

Can anyone tell me why $\phi : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$? Is it a typo? I think it should be $\phi :  \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you very much

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255818/81360) is related

Comment: Note: it's $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for a reason: it denotes the set of *left* cosets.

Comment: @Shaun Why did you mention that?

Comment: Because $\frac{\Bbb Z}{n\Bbb Z}$ betrays a lack of understanding.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you